# Count the rows after single column in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to count the courses in the row manner. It means college name after course are add in a one row

```
College_name    course_name1   course_name2    course_name3    course_name4 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC College     computer       bca             cdb  
xbc college     acvb           bca             ads             abc
xdb college     cgd            ghdg           
vvv college     anb            abd             bca
```

I need a result  format like this in SQL. I need to count the courses:

```
College_name      course_count 
------------------------------
ABC College          3
xbc college          4
xdb college          2     
vvv college          3
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no standard SQL language (even though there is a SQL Standard). What product are you using - Oracle? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Etc. The answer will depend strongly on your product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` :

```
select College_name, count(Course) as course_count 
from (select College_name, course_name1 as Course
      from table 
      union all
      select College_name, course_name2 
      from table 
      . . .
     ) t
group by College_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a very poor data structure.  You should have a `CollegeClasses` table, with one row per college and per class.  Then this would be s simple aggregation.

Instead, you can do a big expression to add stuff:

```
select college_name,
       ( (case when course_name1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when course_name2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when course_name3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when course_name4 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as num_courses
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a combination of unpivoting and grouping:

```
SELECT
  College_name,
  COUNT(course_name) AS course_count
FROM
(
  SELECT
    College_name,
    course_name
  FROM
    table AS t
  UNPIVOT
  (
    course_name for courses in (course_name1, course_name2, course_name3, course_name4)
  ) AS unpiv
) AS d
GROUP BY
  College_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` if you are using `sql-server`

```
SELECT College_name, COUNT(*) course_count 
FROM MyTable 
UNPIVOT( V FOR C IN (course_name1, course_name2, course_name3, course_name4)) UNPVT
GROUP BY College_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the course count by below code please mark it right answer if it work for you

```
select (course_name1 + course_name2 + course_name3 + course_name4 ) as course_count  from (select case when course_name1 is not null then 1 else 0 end as course_name1, case when
 course_name2 is not null then 1 else 0 end as course_name2,
 case when course_name3 is not null then 1 else 0 end as course_name3,case when 
 course_name4 is not null then 1 else 0 end as course_name4
 from desktopschduleremark ) as tst
```

Comment: Why do you need a subquery? Add the return value of the case expressions directly, in a single query. Which is the solution Gordon posted before you posted yours. The very similar, but better option was already available as another Answer. That, plus the shameless self-promotion (basically against this forum's rules) earn you a downvote.

Comment: mathguy i given the answer without seeing other answers given when you go for logic one can apply same logic at same time, when i started giving answer there where no suggestion avaliable and i gave this answer from phone while traveling that why it took time to update